# Why my embedded video resizes automatically?

Tags: html, embedding, wmv

this time I have a page which will load different kinds of file formats, well... i use a switch with php to load the correct player according to the filetype. But when I try to load a wmv file, the video  automatically grows and exceeds the allowed size that i gave the player... i don't know how to prevent that. Here is my code:

```
<object classid="clsid:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95" width="480" height="360" codebase="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/">
<param name="Filename" value="files/' . $file . '">
<param name="AutoStart" value="true">
<param name="ShowControls" value="true">
<param name="BufferingTime" value="2">
<param name="ShowStatusBar" value="true">
<param name="AutoSize" value="false">
<param name="InvokeURLs" value="false">
<embed src="files/' . $file . '" type="application/x-mplayer2" autostart="1" enabled="1" showstatusbar="1" showdisplay="1" showcontrols="1" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" CODEBASE="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=6,0,0,0" width="480" height="360"></embed>
```

Well, I thought the solution was to change "AutoSize" value, i tried false and true, but it keeps doing it. Any ideas?

Comment: Any ideas? I'm still looking for a reason and a way to prevent this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps if you set width: 100% and ensured that any DIV it's in was also 100% that might do the trick.  If not, try `style="width:100% !important"` to override the extra styling code being added.

I use Developer Tools in Chrome (or IE9 or Firebug) to change the styles on the object interactively and see the results immediately.

Comment: Good idea the !important thing. Will try that.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I did some research and i found that it has to do something with the `classid="clsid:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95"` i don't know exactly what it does, but when i changed that to `clsid:05589FA1-C356-11CE-BF01-00AA0055595A`, the player stopped resizing. The problem is, that for some reason, when it loads whatever information it takes from the microsoft page, it adds the following style to my code: `style="WIDTH: 640px; HEIGHT: 549px; TOP: 13px; LEFT: 43px"` and also changes the size and width of the video.

Would be nice if someone could help me research this.